# EKCalendar title crashing app (MonoTouch.EventKit.EKCalendar.set_Title)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, eventkit

I have a problem with EKCalendar from MonoTouch.EventKit. Application is crashing when I try to set a title by a property. It doesn't occur every time, just twice. Here are a fragment of my logs:

```
Apr 29 16:49:19 iPad[973] <Error>: Stacktrace:
Apr 29 16:49:19 iPad[973] <Error>:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
Apr 29 16:49:19 iPad[973] <Error>:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>    
Apr 29 16:49:19 iPad[973] <Error>:   at MonoTouch.EventKit.EKCalendar.set_Title (string) [0x0001b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/EventKit/.pp-EKCalendar.g.cs:134
Apr 29 16:49:19 iPad[973] <Error>:   at OverwriteEKCalendar (MonoTouch.EventKit.EKCalendar) [0x00022] in \Services\Calendar\EKCalendarTouch.cs:229
Apr 29 16:49:19 iPad[973] <Error>:   at Services.Calendar.CalendarService.OverwriteCalendar
```

Code is very simple:

```
public void OverwriteEKCalendar(EKCalendar calendar)
{
    if (this.CGColor != null)
    {
        calendar.CGColor = this.CGColor.ToCGColor();
    }

    calendar.Title = this.Title;
}
```

Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: goto build phase ===> complier sources add "-fobjc-arc" text for EKCaldender all .m files

Comment: It looks like Objective-C threw a native exception, but it's hard to say without more information. Please attach any crash reports (from Xcode's Organizer) and the complete application output.

Comment: It could be a disposed instance (leading to a crash) or a read-only calendar (which could trigger an exception). Since it does not always happen it might be the former (or the calendar state is modified as some point).